# How to implement a method to extract multiple features from a binary image

Tags: java, computer-vision, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I am implementing a simple computer vision system in java. It extracts shapes from an image. Which are generally circular or oval in shape. I have it working to the point where it can create a binary image consisting of only the features I want to analyse. I can find the area of a single feature easily enough by counting the number of white pixels in the image. However if there are multiple features it would find the area of all the features combined.

I was wondering if someone would know how to implement a method to extract/detect multiple features, then I could find the area etc on each easily enough.

I have found information on how to do this with openCV, however I cant find information on how to actually implement a method for myself, or even the theory behind how to achieve it.. It doesnt need to be terribly advanced, even a simple example would be fine.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please mark aardvarkk's answer as the accepted one. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that all of your 'features' are properly connected (4- or 8-connected). If that's the case, the algorithm you're looking for would fall under the umbrella of [connected component labelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_extraction). You can implement the two-pass algorithm described in pseudocode there as a solid beginning.